# How to blacklist a JWT token with Simple JWT (django rest)?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I'm using [Simple JWT](https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt) to use JWT tokens in my Django rest API. It works great but I would like to be able to blacklist a token when a user logs out. In the documentation, it is said:

> If the blacklist app is detected in INSTALLED_APPS, Simple JWT will add any generated refresh or sliding tokens to a list of outstanding tokens. It will also check that any refresh or sliding token does not appear in a blacklist of tokens before it considers it as valid. The Simple JWT blacklist app implements its outstanding and blacklisted token lists using two models: OutstandingToken and BlacklistedToken. Model admins are defined for both of these models. To add a token to the blacklist, find its corresponding OutstandingToken record in the admin and use the admin again to create a BlacklistedToken record that points to the OutstandingToken record.

However, I didn't find any code example and I'm not sure how this should be implemented. An example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: I keep getting `TokenError(_('Token is invalid or expired'))` with `token.blacklist()` utility as mentioned on the docs.

Comment: @qwertzuiop `token_blacklist` is only blacklisting refresh tokens. I am not able to find a way to blacklist jwt access token as well.

Answer (score 8):

Simple JWT only blacklists refresh tokens. This can be done by setting:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist',
    ...
}
```

and then running `migrate`.

So, i would suggest, inorder to logout user:

- Delete both, refresh & access tokens from the client. Also, keep access token expiry as short as possible.
- Black-list the refresh token by creating an api end-point.

  urls.py

  ```py
  path('/api/logout', views.BlacklistRefreshView.as_view(), name="logout"),
  ```

  views.py

  ```py
  from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken

  class BlacklistRefreshView(APIView):
      def post(self, request)
          token = RefreshToken(request.data.get('refresh'))
          token.blacklist()
          return Response("Success")
  ```

This will make sure that the refresh token cannot be used again to generate a new token (if at all someone has acquired it). Also, since access token has short life, it will be invalidated soon hopefully.

Comment: Is there a way to blacklist the access token too? Or waiting is the only option?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about this, but it works for me to use `token.blacklist()`.

`tokens.py`:

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import AccessToken, BlacklistMixin


class JWTAccessToken(BlacklistMixin, AccessToken):
    pass
```

`settings.py`:

```
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    ...
    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('path_to_tokens_py.tokens.JWTAccessToken',),
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error:

> TokenError(_('Token is invalid or expired'))

because of passing the access token in:

```
token = RefreshToken(access_token)
```

while I should pass in the refresh token.

Answer (score 0):

We can blacklist refresh tokens I would use redis with key pair `token[refresh]=access` and check for refresh token with blacklist endpoint

```
path('token/blacklist/', TokenBlacklistView.as_view(), name='token_blacklist'),
```

Send a refresh token
`path('token/verify/', TokenVerifyView.as_view(), name='token_verify'),`
verify your token you would send refresh token.

Use an in-memory database to check blacklist refreshed token
now you can make your end point to check the access list token dont forget to add the following lines in `settings.py`

```
'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': True,
'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True,
```